# Creating multi-item JSON object in localstorage

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to working with both JSON and localStorage.

I am trying to create a small client-side "basket" of sorts which stores a `productID` in my localStorage under the title `cart`.

At present, my `cart` localStorage item is overwritten with a new `productID` instead of having the `productID` added as a new item. Of course the cart object should be able to accept multiple items.

Here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/regVgj

My `addToCart` function is really simple, but I'd not adding the right JSON structure. I'm confused over what the JSON structure should be in this case where multiple items are added but the key is the same (`productID`)

```
function addToCart(productID) {
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(productID));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an array:

```
function addToCart(productID) {
  // Get stored array, if it's not set, it should be set to an empty array
  var basket = localStorage.getItem('cart');
  basket = basket ? JSON.parse(basket) : [];

  basket.push(productID);
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(basket));
}
```